# Java Driver representation of Mongodb aggregation

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following aggregation which Im not able to figure out how to represent in Java/Springboot mongodb driver.

```
db.metric.aggregate([
{ $match: { "key.runid":1} },
 { "$project": {
    "data": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT.metricData" },
        "cond": { "$ne": [ "$$this.k", "_id" ] }
      }
    }
 }},
 { "$unwind": "$data" },
 { "$group": {
   "_id": "$data.k",
   "v": { "$avg": "$data.v" }
 }},
 { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } },
 { "$group": {
   "_id": null,
   "data": { "$push": { "k": "$_id", "v": "$v" } }
 }},
 { "$replaceRoot": { 
   "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$data" }
 }}
])
```

I have attempted the following but being new to this Im not able to figure out how to write the filter for the data field :

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
                match(getCriteriaForMetricKey(keys)),
                project("data", ""));
```

Can someone help me out.

Comment: Where are you up to ? Show us what have you tried so far

Comment: [What close reason should I use for give me teh codez?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253137/2313887). To be clear "this is not a code writing service". If you have a code attempt and you cannot work part of it out, then showing that code and asking the question is fine. Asking to "translate this code" is way off-topic. Let's presume this is a misunderstanding and simply expect your edit to the question showing the reasonable code attempt you have already made.

Comment: Really? Please keep going. The words "reasonable code attemp" should be pretty clear, and this is barely any effort at all. There is nothing difficult right up to the `$replaceRoot`. As the person who even gave you the code I even state that part is even completely optional. I should have taken you seconds to even google how to use `$filter` with spring-mongo, and that's the only stumbling block I really see.